# Not able to turn off power saving option in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, 18.04, power-management

Since I updated to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS, I keep loosing my WiFi connection after a brief period of inactivity,Later I noticed in power saving options there is an option to turn off WiFi to save power, I tried disabling it.

[image]

But turning this option off turns on **Airplane mode**, which completely disables WiFi.
I tried solution given [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269661/how-to-turn-off-wireless-power-management-permanently) but it didn't worked for me, and I am still loosing connection.

Comment: I am also looking for a solution to this.

Comment: Sorry no solution, yet.

Comment: I think it may depend on which wifi drivers you are using as well. I recently bought a new wifi adapter and updated the Linux drivers and now it never disconnects WiFi. PC has been on for about a month.